# Как правильно поступить при сохранении batchInsert?

Tags: yii2

Пытаюсь организовать работу каталога следующим образом это модели `Category`, `CatToProd`, `Product` то есть `Product` связан через `CatToProd` с `Category`. Причем у продуктов может быть множество категорий. Категории у продукта сохраняю следующим образом это вид связанный через контролер с моделью продукт

```
<?=$form->field($model, 'category')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
            'data' => $category,
            'language' => 'en',
            'options' => ['placeholder' => Html::encode('Select Category'),'multiple' => true],
            'pluginOptions' => [
                'allowClear' => true
            ],
        ])->label(false); ?>// $category массив ключ id категории и title
```

таким образом пытаюсь сохранить в модели

```
public function  afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes)
    {
        $this->categorySave($this->category,$this->id);
        parent::afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes); // TODO: Change the autogenerated stub
    }
    protected function categorySave($categorysId,$modelId){
        $batchArr=array();
        foreach ($categorysId as $category){
            $batchArr[]=[$category,$modelId];
        }
        Yii::$app->db->createCommand()->batchInsert('cat_to_prod',['id_category','id_product'],$batchArr)->execute();
    }
```

но тут как говорится неждана параска снискала украинских футболистив. В чем суть при редактировании товара если пытаюсь редактировать категории новые записываются, а если хочу удалить старые они не удаляются. Я даже в идее не могу представить как лучше это организовать. Можете посоветовать куда двигаться.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У Вас же простая связь "many to many" через связующую таблицу.

Вот эта [статья](http://fancode.ru/post/yii2-behaviors-many-to-many) полностью решает Вашу проблему. И не нужно придумывать никаких `afterSave` и тому подобного.

Comment: спасибо за помощь правда там одна ошибка. Вот это `$this->_values[$attributeName]` у меня пусты оказываемтся я так сделал `$this->owner[$attributeName]` но за поведение спасибо